# What does 'but' mean in this sentence from Walden?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

In the first chapter of [Walden](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/205), Thoreau writes:

> Though we are not so degenerate **but** that we might possibly live in a cave or
> a wigwam or wear skins today, it certainly is better to accept the advantages,
> though so dearly bought, which the invention and industry of mankind offer.

Does *but* serve here as a conjunction?
[I've done some research](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Conjunction), but I cannot deduce the meaning of *but* in this sentence.

Comment: It's not a correct expression in modern English.  But you can probably skim over it:  "We are not degenerate.  We could live in a cave or wigwam, but it is better to take advantage of modern technology."

Comment: Similar to [1b: THAT —used after a negative *there is no doubt but he won*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but), although you don't need both "but" and "that".